# Container component in Material UI restricting the size of sibling components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a mock shopping cart and am trying to use MUI while doing so. I currently have two components. A navbar and a list of products (a bunch of cards w/ an image and short description). I have the products contained inside a container and the navbar is implemented using an AppBar component. However, I noticed that the size of my navbar also changes depending on the size of the container, when I actually want it to just take up the width of the entire page.

Tried setting width in the AppBar component, but has no effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.